# How can I set To and Subject fields in an E-Mail being sent by UIDocumentInteractionController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I'm sending an email, with a PDF attachment, while using UIDocumentInteractionController, like this:

I start by showing the PDF file

```
-(void)showPDFFile
{    
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:_filePath];

    if (url) {
        _documentInteractionController =
            [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:url];

        [_documentInteractionController setDelegate: self];
        [_documentInteractionController presentPreviewAnimated:YES];
    }
}


- (UIDocumentInteractionController *)setupControllerWithURL:(NSURL *)fileURL
                                              usingDelegate:(id <UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate>)interactionDelegate {

    UIDocumentInteractionController *interactionController =
        [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileURL];

    [interactionController setDelegate: interactionDelegate];
    return interactionController;
}
```

When the PDF file is shown, the user clicks the "Export" option and the iOS's "Open with" view appears.

Clicking the  email now opens a View Controller ready to send an email.

How would I set the To: CC/BCC and Subject fields programatically?

Thank you!

Comment: are you MFMailComposeViewController  using to present email view ??

Comment: I am not. UIDocumentInteractionController is doing things for me! I'm guessing UIDocumentInteractionController is delegate to MFMailComposeViewController. In any other scenario I would be delegate to MFMailComposeViewController and handle things from there.

Comment: Unfortunately the API doesn't support what you want. Ideally you should be able to use the `annotation` property of the `UIDocumentInteractionController` but it doesn't seem that the mail composer makes use of the property (at least there is no documentation indicating that can be done).

Answer (score 2):

You can assign the mail's subject by using the `UIDocumentInteractionController` `name` property:

```
_documentInteractionController.name = @"My custom mail subject";
```

Unfortunately this is the only attribute I've figured out that can be configured via `UIDocumentInteractionController`.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work any more in iOS 16.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately Florians answer didn't work for me. I had to copy the file locally and then set the URL to the local file.  Setting the name only changed the title on the preview, not the filename or subject in the email.

i.e.

```
NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSError* err = nil;

NSString* newPath = [appDocumentsFolder stringByAppendingPathComponent:name];
if (![fileManager copyItemAtPath:[[NSURL URLWithString:path] path]  toPath:newPath error:&err]) {
    // handle error
}

NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:newPath];

_controller = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:fileURL];
```